# eth_getFilterChanges and uncle blocks

Tags: ether

With `eth_getFilterChanges` rpc-method, I can receive new transactions by existing filter. But as I understand, after receiving transactions by filter these transactions could be from uncle-block, so finally received transactions not exists in blockchain? Is it possible to track such situations?